# Davis-Bacon wage dataset

Tags: data-format, csv

Is anyone aware of a method or source for exporting Davis-Bacon wage information as a csv dataset?

https://www.wdol.gov/archdba.aspx

Assuming you have a particular DBA WD number you are interested in (e.g. WA36) and you wanted to see the relevant wage data across a multi-year time period.

Comment: do you have a list of DBA WD Numbers?